# How to login Azure to retrieve cloud service properties in powershell programmatically?

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to retrieve information regarding my cloud service, like cloud service urls and their ip addresses, etc. To do that, I need login, the normal way to log in Azure through Powershell is using "Login-AzureRmAccount" which will prompt you a login window.

A programmatical way is :

```
$azureAccountName ="your account name"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```

But if my teammates are using the script, they can see my password which I do not expect to.

So my question is : what is the correct way to achieve this without giving out my credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service principal [Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Credential`  It prompts for user and password-

[image]

After this you can run your login command. No need to share/reveal password. Simply run-

```
$psCred = Get-Credential
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```